Conditional expectation of two discrete random values given by the table of joint probabilities
I came across one problem that required quite a bit of work to solve. I'm not sure every step was necessary, but I didn't find either details here (on MSE) or in the first 10 Google links, or books (maybe because it's very simple). So I will allow myself to write it here. Maybe someone will find it useful.
 I would really appreciate it if someone could check my solution.
I. Formulation
Let $X$ and $Y$ are two random variables. The table of joint probabilities:



X \ Y
0
1
2
3




-1
0,02
0,03
0,01
0,09


0
0,04
0,2
0,15
0,1


1
0,05
0,1
0,18
0,03



 Find $\mathbb{E}[XY \mid  |X| + |Y| \leq 2]$.
II. Solution
II.1. Marginal Distributions
I started by finding marginal distributions for $X, Y$. To find them, we need to take the sum of the columns and rows, respectively.
So, random value $X$ takes values $x_i \in \{ -1, 0, 1 \}$ with following probabilities



x_i
P(X = x_i)




-1
0,15


0
0,49


1
0,36



And random value $Y$ takes values $y_j \in \{ 0, 1, 2, 3 \}$ with following probabilities



y_j
P(Y = y_j)




0
0,11


1
0,33


2
0,34


3
0,22



Of course, the sum of these elements must be equal to $1$:
$$
\sum_x \mathsf{P}(X = x) = 1, \qquad \sum_y \mathsf{P}(Y = y) = 1.
$$
I thought it would also be useful to find the distribution of random values $|X|$ and $|Y|$, so I'll leave it here for training purposes.
For $|X|$:



\abs(x_i)
P(X = \abs(x_i))




0
0,49


1
0,51



For $|Y|$ we have the same distribution as for $Y$, because all values are non-negative.
But that doesn't get us any closer to a solution.
So, let introduce two random variables: $Z = X Y$ takes values $z_k \in \{ -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3 \}$ and $U = |X| + |Y|$ takes values $u_l \in \{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4\}$. The question may arise "why are the values the way they are"? The answer is simple: these are all possible values made up from the original values of $X$ and $Y$.
Let's find the probabilities for $\mathsf{P}(Z = z)$:
$$
\mathsf{P}(Z = -3) = \mathsf{P}(X = -1, Y = 3) = 0.09,
$$
$$
\mathsf{P}(Z = -2) = \mathsf{P}(X = -1, Y = 2) = 0.01,
$$
$$
\mathsf{P}(Z = -1) = \mathsf{P}(X = -1, Y = 1) = 0.03,
$$
$$
\mathsf{P}(Z = 0) = \mathsf{P}(X = 0, Y = 0) + \mathsf{P}(X = 0, Y = 1) + \mathsf{P}(X = 0, Y = 2) \\ + \mathsf{P}(X = 0, Y = 3) + \mathsf{P}(X = -1, Y = 0) + \mathsf{P}(X = 1, Y = 0) = 0.56,
$$
$$
\mathsf{P}(Z = 1) = \mathsf{P}(X = 1, Y = 1) = 0.1,
$$
$$
\mathsf{P}(Z = 2) = \mathsf{P}(X = 1, Y = 2) = 0.18,
$$
$$
\mathsf{P}(Z = 3) = \mathsf{P}(X = 1, Y = 3) = 0.03.
$$
Similarly for $U$:
$$
\mathsf{P}(U = 0) = \mathsf{P}(X = 0, Y = 0) = 0.04,
$$
$$
\mathsf{P}(U = 1) = \mathsf{P}(X = 0, Y = 1) + \mathsf{P}(X = -1, Y = 0) + \mathsf{P}(X = 1, Y = 0) = 0.27,
$$
$$
\mathsf{P}(U = 2) = \mathsf{P}(X = 0, Y = 2) + \mathsf{P}(X = -1, Y = 1) + \mathsf{P}(X = 1, Y = 1) = 0.28,
$$
$$
\mathsf{P}(U = 3) = \mathsf{P}(X = 0, Y = 3) + \mathsf{P}(X = -1, Y = 2) + \mathsf{P}(X = 1, Y = 2) = 0.29,
$$
$$
\mathsf{P}(U = 4) = \mathsf{P}(X = -1, Y = 3) + \mathsf{P}(X = 1, Y = 3) = 0.12.
$$
Having dine that, I realised it was unnecessary work:)
II.2. Conditional Expectation
The conditional expectation is, probably, one of the hardest subject in the Probability theory. But we are fortunate in that we have a discrete distribution. Let's $\xi$ (and its values $a$) and $\eta$ (values $b$) are random variables. Define conditional expectation as follows
$$
\mathbb{E}[\xi \mid \eta] = \sum_{b} \mathbb{E}[\xi \mid \eta = b] I(\eta = b).
$$
This is very logical: we simply take the values of $\eta$ and find the expectation of $\xi$ at a fixed value of $\eta$. But what is $\sum_{\alpha} \mathbb{E}[\xi \mid \eta = b]$? Let's describe:
$$
\sum_{\alpha} \mathbb{E}[\xi \mid \eta = b] = \sum_{a} a \mathsf{P}(\xi = a \mid \eta = b).
$$
What can be transformed using definition of conditional probability into
$$
\sum_{a} a \mathsf{P}(\xi = a \mid \eta = b) = \dfrac{\sum_a a \mathsf{P}(\xi = a, \eta = b)}{\mathsf{P}(\eta = b)} = \dfrac{\mathbb{E}[\xi I(\eta = b)]}{\mathsf{P}(\eta = b)}.
$$
Note that the conditional expectation is a function of $b$:
$$
\sum_{\alpha} \mathbb{E}[\xi \mid \eta = b] = \phi(b).
$$
Thus, we can find the conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}[Z \mid U]$ as follows:
$$
\mathbb{E}[Z \mid U = 0] = \sum_z z \mathsf{P}(Z = z \mid U = 0) = 0,
$$
$$
\mathbb{E}[Z \mid U = 1] = \sum_z z \mathsf{P}(Z = z \mid U = 1) = 0,
$$
$$
\mathbb{E}[Z \mid U = 2] = \sum_z z \mathsf{P}(Z = z \mid U = 2) = -1 \mathsf{P}(Z = -1 \mid U = 2) + 1 \mathsf{P}(Z = 1 \mid U = 2) = -1 \cdot 0.03 + 1 \cdot 0.1 = 0.07,
$$
$$
\mathbb{E}[Z \mid U = 3] = \sum_z z \mathsf{P}(Z = z \mid U = 3) = -2 \mathsf{P}(Z = -2 \mid U = 3) + 2 \mathsf{P}(Z = 2 \mid U = 3) = -2 \cdot 0.01 + 2 \cdot 0.18 = 0.34,
$$
$$
\mathbb{E}[Z \mid U = 4] = \sum_z z \mathsf{P}(Z = z \mid U = 4) = 3 \mathsf{P}(Z = 3 \mid U = 4) = 0.09.
$$
Finally,
$$
\mathbb{E}[Z \mid U] = 0 \cdot I(U = 1) + 1 \cdot I(U = 2) + 0.07 \cdot I(U = 2) + 0.34 \cdot I(U = 3) + 0.09 \cdot I(U = 4).
$$
NB: Conditional expectation is a random value!
II.3. The Answer
Completing the solution of the original problem, we obtain the following answer
$$
\mathbb{E}[XY \mid  |X| + |Y| \leq 2] = 0.07.
$$
P.S. I apologise for the non-perfect style. I don't understand how to apply some tex commands here (e.g. tables).

I have no formal education here, which explains why I find the analysis in the posted question rather weird.
The steps that I would follow to compute the exact answer are as follows:

Step 1 
I would completely ignore any data, other than the original formulation chart.

Step 2
I would manually reject any of the $~12~$ entries from that chart that represented a situation where $~|X| + |Y| > 2.$ 
This would consist of the $~(X,Y)~$ entries of $~(0,3), (1,2), (1,3), (-1,2), (-1,3).~$ 
The remainder of my steps would then focus solely on the $~7 ~(X,Y)~$ entries that have not been rejected.

Step 3
I would let $~W~$ represent the sum of the probabilities associated with each of these $~7~$ remaining entries. 
Then, I would let $~c~$ represent a scaling factor, such that 
$~c \times W = 1 \implies c = \dfrac{1}{W},~$ and immediately scale each of the $~7~$ entries by multiplying each one by $~c.~$ 
This way, the sum of the $~7~$ (remaining) adjusted probability entries equals $~1.~$ 

Step 4
I would form a new chart that has exactly  $~7~$ entries, where each entry corresponds to one of the $~7~$ remaining $~(X,Y)~$ entries.  
In this new chart, each entry would consist of a Key and Value, where the key $~= (X \times Y),~$ and the value $~=~$ the adjusted (i.e. scaled) probability assigned to this specific $~(X,Y)~$ entry.

Step 5
I would then identify each distinct key of $~(X \times Y)~$ that shows in the chart in Step 4.  Presumably, there will be less than $~7~$ distinct keys, because (for example) the entries of $~(X=0,Y=1)~$ and $~(X=0,Y=2),~$ will both yield the same value for $~(X \times Y).~$

Step 6
Assume that you have $~n~$ distinct keys from Step 5. 
I would denote these keys as $~K_1, K_2, \cdots, K_n.~$ 
For each $~r \in \{1,2,\cdots,n\},~$ 
I would then assign an overall probability $~p(K_r)~$ by adding all of the probabilities (i.e. values) associated with an $~(X,Y)~$ entry from the chart in Step 4 that produced the key of $~(X \times Y) = K_r.~$ 
At this point, you should have that 
$\displaystyle \sum_{r=1}^n p(K_r) = 1.$

Step 7 
Then, the expected value of $~(X \times Y)~$ will be given by 
$\displaystyle \sum_{r=1}^n \left[ ~K_r \times p(K_r) ~\right].$


Edit 
In retrospect, while the detailing of Steps 5, 6, and 7 provide a nice orderly attack on the original poster's intuition, these steps may be eliminated by the following shortcut:
Immediately following Step 4, for $~r \in \{1,2,\cdots,7\},~$ you could (instead) let $~K_r~$ denote the key, $~(X \times Y)~$ of the $~r$-th entry, and $~p(K_r)~$ denote the probability associated with the $~r$-th entry.  Then, you would have that the expected value is
$~\displaystyle \sum_{r=1}^{7} \left[ ~K_r \times p(K_r) ~\right].$
